# Does an <img> tag load along side with the rest of the page or after?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML programming and I'm trying to understand the `<img>` tag in html

but I cannot understand when the image is being loaded
for example in this code:

```css
#pic
{
display:inline-block;
 background-image:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg');
 height:20rem;
 width:35rem;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello how are you?</div>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"> 

 <br>
 <span id="pic"></span>
 
 <div>I'm good wbu?</div>
```

Is the `<img>` being loaded first or after or simultaneously while the other tags are being loaded?
What exactly is the order of the DOM elements loading when a browser loads a new webpage?
Do the same rules apply to the `background-image` ?

Comment: I think `img` tags and others are considered quasi-simultaneously by a browser (and in the order it reads them), but images generally take much more time than standard text to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html code is rendered line by line , in your code img tag is rendered after your first div tag, you give https src to the image,
Browser rendering machine doesn't wait whenever image is available and then rendered the next line. That's why you have seen that sometimes at the beginning we can see all the part of website except image.

Img tag is rendered with like all the tag. But to render image it takes time

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks @Ravi Gajera. The only thing is that the browser will finish loading big images after small ones.